# Дата по-русски через setlocale

Tags: php, локаль

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "ru_RU.CP1251");
$date = strftime("%d %B, %H:%M",strtotime($row['date']));
```

Почему-то, если использовать код выше, то вроде все ок, дату выводит, но месяц по-прежнему выводится по-английски: `26 May, 21:24`. Если использовать:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "ru_RU");
$date = strftime("%d %B, %H:%M",strtotime($row['date']));
```

То дата выводится коряво: `26 јРЩ, 21:24`

Как исправить?

Comment: Используйте UTF-8, пожжжжалуйста! ))

Answer (score 2):

Используйте лучше готовую библиотеку или свой класс для этого, который не будет зависеть от локали и настроек сервера. Например вот мое решение, которое использую на всех проектах [TimeHelper.php](https://github.com/korytoff/PHP-TimeHelper)