# Strtotime на русском языке

Tags: php, ввод, дата

Поиск не увенчался, хотел бы задать вопрос: существует ли функция strtotime() на русском языке? То есть чтобы пользователь, допустим, написал "1 год назад", а я получил long c сотворения unix.

Сразу хотел бы уточнить, что речь не о выводе, как в этой статье - [Дата по-русски через setlocale](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/114253/php-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-setlocale) - а о вводе.

Может быть, strtotime можно локализовать? Какой-то словарь там подцепить или типа того?

Comment: А я вот ни черта не понял :) разжуйте пожалуйста вопрос и положите в голову..

Comment: Жую: пользователь пишет в поле даты "первый день прошлого месяца", или "завтра", а я пишу в БД unix timestamp. strtotime() все это умеет, вот только понимает по-английски. У вас теперь есть ответ есть такая же на русском?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько помню, подобный функционал я видел на хабре... Да, точно, вот та статья:

**[250 строк кода, распознающих дату на русском языке](http://habrahabr.ru/post/204628/)**

Это + AJAX дадут вам представление, как реализовать нужный вам функционал.

Comment: Портировать эту лапшу на php нереально, я-то ведь рассчитывал на халяву, понимаете? Как бы там ни было, ставлю отвечено, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Забавная проблема. ИМХО, Вы в каком-то нелогичном направлении думаете.

Ну а по вопросу - http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.formats.relative.php - берете все вариации, переводите. А дальше монотонная работа с регулярками

Comment: Направление гуманное и логичное дать юзеру возможность _нормально_ вписывать дату, а не принуждать тыкать в клетки календаря и мотать годы, месяцы и дни. Значит, никому еще не надо было, если не перевели?

Comment: @kostyanet, уж больно много мороки с кириллицей... 

(проще переучить пользователей на английский).

Comment: @kostyanet, нужен просто массив для сопоставления названий на разных языках. И все!