# Конвертирование даты: строка - дата

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Есть дата «Сентябрь 2015» ее устанавливает пользователь. Мне требуется сделать отчет за месяц по этой дате. Как перевести «Сентябрь 2015» к примеру в 09.2015. Может есть стандартные функции?  (те что я находил не работают).
Можно JS можно PHP  чем проще.
Может есть что-то подобное strtotime(php)

Comment: А если он введет "синтябрь" - что делать будете? Дайте юзеру выпадающий список с месяцами и получайте оттуда не строку, а номер месяца.

Comment: не не  ввод всегда фиксирован из календаря datepicker

Comment: Есть неплохая js библиотека [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: @Raaur, боюсь, вы как-то неправильно используете свой datepicker. Неужели он не дает возможности извлечь числовое представление месяца, года, дня?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дата должна быть в формате 09.2015
Именно в таком формате она должна приходить из браузера, где её устанавливает пользователь. Что он при этом *видит* на экране - это другой вопрос.

Comment: да да именно дата может быть даже и 01.09.15

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.su/strftime - это раз
[Strtotime на русском языке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/369805/strtotime-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5) - это два
думаю, материала хватит. ну, а если у вас именно "сентябрь 2015", и никаких других вариантов написания даты - то проще всего через substr обрезать последние 5 символов, и вручную прописать замену названия месяца на число.

Comment: substr ну да им можно разобрать и сравнивать с массивом месяцев. Так я могу. а может есть стандартная функция ?

Comment: если вы используете datepicker - то просто выводите выбранное значение в нужном формате. посмотрите документацию, там это точно должно быть.

Comment: на экран одно а при выводе другое. ок спс на направление щас буду копать

Answer (score 0):

```
function parse(text) {
  var months = [/январь\s*(\d+)/i, /февраль\s*(\d+)/i, /март\s*(\d+)/i, /апрель\s*(\d+)/i, /май\s*(\d+)/i, /июнь\s*(\d+)/i, /июль\s*(\d+)/i, /август\s*(\d+)/i, /сентябрь\s*(\d+)/i, /октябрь\s*(\d+)/i, /ноябрь\s*(\d+)/i, /декабрь\s*(\d+)/i];

  var q, match;

  for (q=0; q<months.length; ++q) {
    if((match = text.match(months[q]) /* assignment */)) {
      return new Date(match[1], q, 1);
    }
  }
}

parse("Сентябрь 2015")
// Tue Sep 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Russia TZ 2 Standard Time)
```

А вообще, не надо давать пользователю вводить дату текстом.
Парсить имеет смысл только если внешний сервис присылает дату в таком формате.